# how to convert action script 3 to c#?

Tags: c#, actionscript-3

all.

I am trying to parse some binary(AMF3) data using C#.

And I have found some useful class and functions from https://code.google.com/p/cvlib/source/browse/trunk/as3/com/coursevector/amf/AMF3.as

And it has got a static function below.

```
class UUIDUtils {

    private static var UPPER_DIGITS:Array = [
        '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7',
        '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'
        ];

    public static function fromByteArray(ba:ByteArray):String {
        if (ba != null && ba.length == 16) {
            var result:String = "";
            for (var i:int = 0; i < 16; i++) {
                if (i == 4 || i == 6 || i == 8 || i == 10) result += "-";

                result += UPPER_DIGITS[(ba[i] & 0xF0) >>> 4];
                result += UPPER_DIGITS[(ba[i] & 0x0F)];
            }
            return result;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

It looks like Java, but it's not.

And I think it's Action Script 3.

Anyway, I came across here to convert it to C#.

So my code would look like below.

```
static string[] UPPER_DIGITS = { "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F" };

static string FromAMF3ByteArray(byte[] ba)
{
    if (ba != null && ba.Length == 16) {
        string result   = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        {
            if (i == 4 || i == 6 || i == 8 || i == 10)
                result += "-";

            result += UPPER_DIGITS[(ba[i] & 0xF0) >>> 4];
            result += UPPER_DIGITS[(ba[i] & 0x0F)];
        }
        return result;
    }

    return null;
}
```

But I am getting syntax error at result += UPPER_DIGITS[(ba[i] & 0xF0) >>> 4];.

Anyone can give me some advise about >>> ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`>>>` is a [bitwise unsigned right shift](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/operators.html#bitwise_unsigned_right_shift) operator in ActionScript. It's equivalent to a [right-shift operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xt18et0d.aspx) in C# when applied to an unsigned type (byte, uint, ulong).  Please find below the correct translation:

```
private static string FromAMF3ByteArray(byte[] ba)
{
    if (ba != null && ba.Length == 16)
    {
        string result = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        {
            if (i == 4 || i == 6 || i == 8 || i == 10) result += "-";

            result += UPPER_DIGITS[(ba[i] & 0xF0) >> 4];
            result += UPPER_DIGITS[(ba[i] & 0x0F)];
        }
        return result;
    }

    return null;
}
```